# avoiding race condition in javascript

Tags: jquery, session, race-condition

I have a website for exams. I save the test time in sessionstorage to avoid the time being repeated when the page is refreshed and will only be repeated when the next test starts. but in some cases the time for test 2 still takes the time from test 1. after ask and searching i think that is a race condition.
My assumption is that when the `nextButton` button is pressed it successfully removes the session. but in `countdownTimer` which always sets a session every second it overwrites sessions that have been deleted.

here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  displaytest(testId, indexSubtest);
});

function displaytest(testId, indexSubtest) {
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
      countdownTImer();

      var nextButton = $("#nextButton");
      var finishButton = $("#finishButton");

      nextButton.click(function () {
        indexSubtest++;
        sessionStorage.setItem("indexSubtest", indexSubtest);
        sessionStorage.removeItem("timeSubtest");
      });
      finishButton.click(function () {
        storeAnswer(stored);
      });
    },
    error: function (error) {
      console.error("error:", error);
    },
  });
}

function countdownTImer() {
  const isActiveSubtest = sessionStorage.getItem("indexSubtest");
  let time = sessionStorage.getItem("timeSubtest");

  if (!time) {
    time = dataUjian.subtest[isActiveSubtest - 1].subtesDurations[0];
    sessionStorage.setItem("timeSubtest", time);
  }

  var x = setInterval(function () {
    time -= 1;
    sessionStorage.setItem("timeSubtest", time);
    const seconds = time % 60;
    const secondsInMinutes = (time - seconds) / 60;
    const minutes = secondsInMinutes % 60;

    document.getElementById("timeTest").innerHTML =
      minutes + "m:" + seconds + "s";

    if (time < 0 ) {
      sessionStorage.removeItem("timeSubtest");
      forceFinish(1, isActiveSubtest);
      clearInterval(x);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

This is difficult to detect because it occurs randomly; some people experience it, while others do not.

Is this a true case of race condition or something else?

Comment: You should probably remove any previously registered click handlers on your _next_  and _finish_ buttons

Comment: What makes it necessary to do it?

Comment: Every time you use `nextButton.click(function() { ... })` it **adds** an event listener. When you click the button, **all** the registered listeners will be executed

Comment: Race conditions can't generally happen in JavaScript, because it's not multi-threaded.